# Microsoft Power Apps formula chaining in a data card value field

Tags: formula, powerapps

I have data coming as `{"abc", 1, CE}`. I would like to replace the braces and split it and display it in a data card. I want the first function output to be the input of the second function

First I am trying to use **Substitute** to replace the curly braces and it's not working.

I tried the following

```
Substitute(Parent.Default,"{","");Substitute(Parent.Default,"}","");

Substitute(Parent.Default,"{","");;Substitute(Parent.Default,"}","");;

Text(Concurrent(Substitute(Parent.Default,"{","");;Substitute(Parent.Default,"}","")))

Text(Concurrent(Substitute(Parent.Default,"{","");Substitute(Parent.Default,"}","")))
```

The following works fine with just one.

```
Substitute(Parent.Default,"{","")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Substitute function doesn't change the argument that you pass to it; instead, it returns a new string with the substitution applied. So if you want to remove both curly braces, you need to use an expression similar to the one below:

```
Substitute(Substitute(Parent.Default, "{", ""), "}", "")
```

Comment: Great!! That works. Now I am trying to use Split along with like below and that doesn't work. Any idea to fix that?


Split(Substitute(Substitute(Parent.Default, "{", ""), "}", ""),",")

Comment: Using a listbox control and the formula Split(Substitute(Substitute(ThisItem.names, "{", ""), "}", ""),",")  worked